# Ошибка object

Tags: mysqli, php

Подскажите в чем проблема на что ругается?

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /home/u373495774/public_html/registration.php on line 101
```

Код:

строка 101

```
$new_user_sql = "Insert into `users` (`login`,`mail`,`password`,`name`,`lastname`,`city`,`ip`,`date`,`group`) VALUES (
  '$login','$mail','$password','$name','$lastname','$city','$ip','$date','$group')";
        $new_user = mysqli_query($link,$new_user_sql);
print "<p>Вы успешно зарегистрированы, спасибо за регистрацию!</p>";}}
```

Comment: Что из этого является 101 строчкой? Подозреваю что вы её не вставили сюда.

Comment: $new_user_sql = "Insert into `users` (`login`,`mail`,`password`,`name`,`lastname`,`city`,`ip`,`date`,`group`) VALUES (
  '$login','$mail','$password','$name','$lastname','$city','$ip','$date','$group')";
        $new_user = mysqli_query($link,$new_user_sql);
print "<p>Вы успешно зарегистрированы, спасибо за регистрацию!</p>";}}

Comment: Ну если это все у вас 101 строка, то я вас поздравляю, вы быдлокодер! :)) Извините, если оскорбил. По факту - на строки хоть разбейте, а то у вас три операции в одной строчке, не по понятиям как-то!

Comment: Господи не догадаться головочкой что у меня выше код?

Comment: Ну что это код, то это понятно. Я просто говорю о том, что если весь этот код и есть 101 строка, то это не есть хорошо с точки зрения юзабилити и удобочитаемости плюс дебаг-удобности. Вот скажите мне, исходя из вашей 101 строки кода, какая операция вызывает эту ошибку: присваивание $new_user_sql строки, вызов ф-и mysqli_query() или все-таки print() ?? Извините за откровенный оффтоп...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что вы пытаетесь сделать что-то, что нам не показали. Нету ли у вас в коде чего0-нить подобного?:

```
print $new_user;
```

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что разработчик посчитал, что для класса mysqli_result не допустимо преобразование в строку и скорее всего добавил в магический метод mysqli_result::__toString() выброс исключения при попытке его вызвать.