# Ошибка перевода object to string

Tags: php, mysqli

При выборке ругается так:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be
>   converted to string ... on line
>   232

`230->    echo"`
`231->    <div class='bo_pol'>`
`232->    <p><span class='otmetki'>".$com_pol."</span> | Полезность</p>`
`233->    </div>";`

Помимо этой строки переменная $com_pol - используется здесь:

`209->    $com_pol = mysqli_query($link, "select sum(otzi_bal) as summ from comm_rate WHERE otzi_id='1'");`

Собственно из-за нижней строки и происходит ошибка. В самой sql запрос выполняется правильно и выдает нужный результат.
(Смотрела похожую тему [Ошибка object](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/296584/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-object) Но как поправить не поняла )
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysqli_query($link, "select sum(otzi_bal) as summ from comm_rate WHERE otzi_id='1'")->fetch_assoc()['summ'];
```

Comment: Я поняла свою ошибку. Это действительно глупо как то получилось.
Еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Из [описания](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php) `mysqli_query`

> Возвращает FALSE в случае неудачи. В случае успешного выполнения запросов SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE или EXPLAIN mysqli_query() вернет объект mysqli_result. Для остальных успешных запросов mysqli_query() вернет TRUE.

У Вас используется `SELECT`. Тогда правильный код будет таким

```
$res = mysqli_query(
  $link,
  "select sum(otzi_bal) as summ from comm_rate WHERE otzi_id='1'"
);
if (!$res)
  die(mysqli_error($link));
$com_pol = $res->fetch_row()[0];
$res->close();
```